# RCP about dialog opening in full width

Tags: dialog, size, eclipse-rcp

I have a problem with my RCP application.  When I open the about dialog, it opens up with the full width of the screen, which makes it looks quite odd.

Is there a way to adjust the default about dialog box?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com ?

Comment: Some code would be useful to get an answer.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

why do not try running eclipse application using command promt unsing -clean as argument

eclipse.exe - clean